About $\mathbf{C}\otimes_\mathbf{R}\mathbf{H}\cong\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbf{C})$
Let $\mathbf{H}$ be the Hamiltonian quaternions.
I want to prove that $\mathbf{C}\otimes_\mathbf{R}\mathbf{H}\cong\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbf{C})$, but I have no idea on constructing the isomorphism. Is there any hint about this question? Thank you!

What did you try so far?
